# Instruments crashed on startup when Appium server is launched

Tags: ios, appium

Instruments are getting crashed when the Appium server is launched.

Could anyone please tell me what is the reason for this?

Comment: I've seen this happen when the configuration is for a simulator, but specifies a UUID; or vice versa--the configuration is for a device but specifies simulator settings.

Comment: No, I am using real device and it is configured for devices not for simulator.

Comment: without logs it'll be hard to tell, imagine : "*My car won't start, please help me...*"

Comment: Now I am getting this log...error: uncaughtException: spawn EACCES date=Wed Jun 10 2015 13:50:31 GMT+0530 (IST), pid=1119, uid=501, gid=20, cwd=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium, execPath=/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node, version=v0.12.4, argv=[/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node, /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/server/main.js, --command-timeout, 7200, --pre-launch, --debug-log-spacing, --platform-version, 8.3, --platform-name, iOS

Comment: Are you using debug build ?

Comment: 1. Are you able to access the instruments in ways other than appium script? 2. Also please make sure you have `Use Native Instruments Library` checked under `Advance settings` for IOS platform in Appium's UI. 3. `Enable UI Automation` setting in setting--developer